# Replacing certain lines using awk

Tags: xml, awk

I have the following xml file

```
<parameters pca-dim="32"/>
<parameters resize_minpix="100000" npix="100000" ptch="24" step="4" nscale="5" maxscale="4"/>
<parameters notify-classes-removed="1"/>
<parameters grid-regions="1x1,1x3"/>
<feature_extractions>
<feature_extraction id="orh" params="8,4:0.7,0.5:0.4,0.6:0.01"/>
<feature_extraction id="col" params="4:mv:0.4,0.6:0.01"/>
</feature_extractions>
<vocabulary rebuild="IfDoesNotExist" gmm-iter="8" sig-norm-type="l2" sig-norm-pow="0.5"/>
<classifier type="sgd" lambda="1.0E-5" max-iterations="20"/>
<validation name="V1CrossValidation" folds="5" mode="fast" method="modulo" result-file="/opt/ADL_db/Users/mkhalil/CshellTest/ScriptTests/temp/V1CrossValidation-results.stats" score-flags="combine,normalize"/>
</gvcmodelinfo>
<classes>
<class name="Car">
<imageset imagedb="/opt/ADL_db/Users/mkhalil/runtime-ImageDB/DB1/db.xml" path="//image/scenes/scene[((@name="Car" or starts-with(@name,"Car")))]/ancestor::image"/>
</class>
<class name="MotorCycle">
<imageset imagedb="/opt/ADL_db/Users/mkhalil/runtime-ImageDB/DB1/db.xml" path="//image/scenes/scene[((@name="MotorCycle" or starts-with(@name,"MotorCycle")))]/ancestor::image"/>
</class>
<class name="Van">
<imageset imagedb="/opt/ADL_db/Users/mkhalil/runtime-ImageDB/DB1/db.xml" path="//image/scenes/scene[((@name="Van" or starts-with(@name,"Van")))]/ancestor::image"/>
</class>
</classes>
</gvcmodel>
```

And I would like to replace 2 things:

1. `/opt/ADL_db/Users/mkhalil/CshellTest/ScriptTests/temp/V1CrossValidation-results.stats` to `/opt/ADL_db/Users/mkhalil/code/V1CrossValidation-results.stats`
2. `/opt/ADL_db/Users/mkhalil/runtime-ImageDB/DB1/db.xml` to `/opt/ADL_db/Users/mkhalil/code/db.xml`

And create a new xml file with the output.

Comment: What have you tried?  Also, note that if you're stuck using awk for some reason, your solution will be limited because awk does not natively understand XML. It would be much better to use a language that, like perl, php, python, ruby, etc. Or you could explore using one of the awk or gawk extensions that add basic XML support to awk.  Google "xml awk" for some ideas. Come back and post a question once you have some code for us to help you with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed -e 's/\/opt\/ADL_db\/Users\/mkhalil\/CshellTest\/ScriptTests\/temp\/V1CrossValidation-results.stats/\/opt\/ADL_db\/Users\/mkhalil\/code\/V1CrossValidation-results.stat‌​s/g' \
-e 's/\/opt\/ADL_db\/Users\/mkhalil\/runtime-ImageDB\/DB1\/db.xml/\/opt\/ADL_db\/Users\/mkhalil\/code\/db.xml/g' input.xml >new.xml
```

Comment: Yes you can use awk too. But sed suits better for this purpose

Comment: note that if you use a different delimiter you don't have to escape slashes, which will make it more readable and easy to copy/paste.